# Best jQuery Plugin For News

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

i have 10 images and i want to show they with numbers(1,2,3,4,5...). I am talking about image slideshow with numbers. Can you suggest me jquery plugin for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycle is nice and flexible. Check out the advacned examples [Cycle Link](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/)

Answer (score 1):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/VisualLightbox

I tried several (of the many available plugins on the jquery website) and finally decided on this one.